# Enabling management of content types on SharePoint lists via web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, list, content-type

I can enable the management of content types in a document library's "advanced settings". Is there any web service method for this?  I need to do this in an automated way, not manually.

It seems like neither Lists.AddList nor Lists.UpdateList can set the value of the "Flags" attribute that is needed for this. My web service client has alread created a new content type and has associated this content type with the list. But without enabling the management of content types, the new type won't appear in the "New" drop-down menu, for example.

Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web services are limited compared to what is available using the object model. If you can't find it in the web services SDK (I can't) then unfortunately it doesn't exist.

If you can use the object model, see [SPList.ContentTypesEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.contenttypesenabled.aspx). Otherwise, you will need to [create your own web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx) that flips the bit on this particular property.

Comment: Yup, I just spent all afternoon searching for this and can't find it anywhere. It seems like it **should** be a part of the `Lists.UpdateList` method.